# Customized ComboBox Style in DatagridTemploateColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: wpf-controls

I have customised a default ComboBox Style by using DataGrid in the popup (dropdown) as described [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1359/wpf-datagrid-as-combobox-dropdown.aspx).

When I use the customised style in a **ComboBox** or in a **DatagridComboBoxColumn**, it works fine.

Similary when I use the style in the **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate**, it works fine.

However, it does not work when used in a **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate**. The selection does not work at all. It is as if the selection changed event does not fire.
I tried setting the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" in the ComboBox, still it does not work.

Funny enough when I use the default ComboBox style in **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate**, it works. It appears the problem is when Datagrid is used as an ItemsHost.

The reason why I want to use it in a **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate** is because I want to change the look of my application by not using the standard DataGridComboBoxColumn where the editing part is hidden and one has to dig deeper to exopause the comboxbox. I want the user to click once to select items from the combobox.

Similarly the DataGridTemplateColumn is wired in such a way that the CellEditingTemplate is underneath the CellTemplate (which is similar to the default DatagridComboxBox). What I want instead is to use the **DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate**  for both viewing and selecting (editing).

At the same time I don't want to use the default ComboBox Style by replacing the ItemsHost with a Datagrid. But the customised style does not work in a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate. It only works in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate

Any dies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by inserting these two lines in the Datagrid

**SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem}"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"**